# merging data that is separated by a space in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am currently plotting my data which displays the activity levels for an animal before and after she gave birth.

[image: here is plot]

On the x axis is date (so, day month here) and on the right is activity. As you can see, there is a small gap which was due to collar malfunction. For visual purposes, is it possible to set the data from July 2015 (and upwards) directly next to April 2015 so that the points are sitting right next to one another rather than being separate? I would provide sample data, however, I am still trying to figure out how to do that, however, my R script is the following:

```
c<-ggplot(ii,aes(y=ii$newavx2, x=ii$datenew, color=infant))+ ylim(1.5,5.9)+ stat_smooth(method=lm)+ geom_point()
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Not possible with ggplot2, at least not without a hack or workaround. This is a purposeful omission on the part of the package developers, because plots with axis breaks can be misleading.  Some other graphics packages have functionality to do axis breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The first thought of mine is you should put the color in `aes()` to `geom_point` if you want the fitted equation to be linear instead of truncated.

If it's the problem of the missing date, you should consider using `factor(x)` like

```
ggplot(ii,aes(y=ii$newavx2, x=factor(ii$datenew)) + geom_point
```

so that the ggplot2 could merge the near truncated date together without leaving any time gap.

However, I don't know if I understand exactly the question. It'd better if you provide some reproducible data set.